# Error jquery : Uncaught TypeError: $(...).DataTable is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring-boot, datatables, thymeleaf

I tried for tow days to add search field and sorting data table using jquery but always i show this error :

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).DataTable is not a function

I changed the script source order but can't run

PS : I'm using thymeleaf, bootstrap

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
  <link th:replace="fragments/header :: header" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.16/b-1.5.1/b-flash-1.5.1/datatables.min.css" />
  <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-2.2.4.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.16/b-1.5.1/b-flash-1.5.1/datatables.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div th:replace="fragments/menu :: menu"></div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <h1>Listado de Provinces</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <a href="/createprovince" class="btn btn-primary a-btn-slide-text">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span><strong>Crear Province</strong></span>
      </a>
      <a href="/home" class="btn btn-secondary btn-lg active" role="button" aria-pressed="true">Home</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <table id="example" class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">Nombre</th>
        <th scope="col">Opciones</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr th:each="province : ${provinces}">
        <td th:text="${province.name}"></td>
        <td class="options">
          <a th:href="@{'/provinces/edit/' + ${province.id_province}}" class="btn btn-primary a-btn-slide-text">
            <span><strong>Modificar</strong></span>
          </a>
          <a th:href="@{'/provinces/delete/' + ${province.id_province}}" class="btn btn-delete a-btn-slide-text" onclick="return confirm('¿Estas seguro?');">
            <span><strong>Borrar</strong></span>
          </a>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#example').DataTable({
        "pagingType": "full_numbers"
      });
    });
  </script>
  <div th:replace="fragments/footerscripts :: footer"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

[This a screen shoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RLlxi.png)

Comment: Did you clear your browser cache?

Comment: Post *actual* HTML, not pseudo code.

Comment: Looks like that jquery file you are using is corrupt - if you change it for the one from https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js the above snippet starts to work

Comment: Any particular reason why jQuery is being loaded on `http` while the DataTables plugin's JS in `https`?

Comment: Review queue, note user's self-answer: "source of the problem was a conflict with anathor jquery local file"

Answer (score 0):

1. This error comes because of this code snippet did not take the insecure link so you put https://  for loading data tables. check it with other editor with http:// that woks for me.
2. the body of the first column have no values. data tables shows this type if errors and alert because missed values.

some times the

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
  <link th:replace="fragments/header :: header" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.16/b-1.5.1/b-flash-1.5.1/datatables.min.css" />
  <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-2.2.4.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.16/b-1.5.1/b-flash-1.5.1/datatables.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#example').DataTable({
        "pagingType": "full_numbers"
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div th:replace="fragments/menu :: menu"></div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <h1>Listado de Provinces</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <a href="/createprovince" class="btn btn-primary a-btn-slide-text">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span><strong>Crear Province</strong></span>
      </a>
      <a href="/home" class="btn btn-secondary btn-lg active" role="button" aria-pressed="true">Home</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <table id="example" class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">Nombre</th>
        <th scope="col">Opciones</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr th:each="province : ${provinces}">
        <td th:text="${province.name}">1</td>
        <td class="options">
          <a th:href="@{'/provinces/edit/' + ${province.id_province}}" class="btn btn-primary a-btn-slide-text">
            <span><strong>Modificar</strong></span>
          </a><br/>
          <a th:href="@{'/provinces/delete/' + ${province.id_province}}" class="btn btn-delete a-btn-slide-text" onclick="return confirm('¿Estas seguro?');">
            <span><strong>Borrar</strong></span>
          </a>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr th:each="province : ${provinces}">
        <td th:text="${province.name}">2</td>
        <td class="options">
          <a th:href="@{'/provinces/edit/' + ${province.id_province}}" class="btn btn-primary a-btn-slide-text">
            <span><strong>Modificar</strong></span>
          </a><br/>
          <a th:href="@{'/provinces/delete/' + ${province.id_province}}" class="btn btn-delete a-btn-slide-text" onclick="return confirm('¿Estas seguro?');">
            <span><strong>Borrar</strong></span>
          </a>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  
  <div th:replace="fragments/footerscripts :: footer"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer, i resolved the problem. The source of the problem was a conflict with anathor jquery local file